# Logic textbook reference request

Tags: logic, reference-request

I am looking for the name and author of a textbook on predicate logic that is primarily used in philosophy courses on introductory logic.  The only thing I remember about the book is that the last section was a proof of Church's theorem.  The author of this book, I believe, also co-wrote a well known book on computability, that I cannot find either.

Answer (score 2):

Richard Epstein - Predicate Logic

He also wrote a book on Classical Mathematical Logic, and another book on computability.

Comment: I think that's it.  I was thrown off by the weird covers on amazon.

Comment: @Fractal7 Hi, can you give some comments on Epstein's book(both)? Is it clearly written, rigorous or friendly? And how does it compare to others?
 Thanks. :)

Comment: The only one I fully worked through was the one on classical mathematical logic, to help me get a better appreciation for material that was skimmed over in my proofs course. It came across as clear and was helpful. (I just saw this one and happened to know the answer, I am not qualified to compare it to other texts).

Comment: Actually, it's not him!  I was looking for Richard Jeffery.  He wrote Computability and Logic, and Formal Logic: Its Scope and Limits.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are searching for Elliott Mendelson - Introduction to Mathematical Logic: it has the Church's Theorem in the last section or so.

Comment: Don't think that's him.  This book is strictly predicate logic, it doesn't go into model theory or anything (except for the last chapter which has some computability).  The proof of Church's theorem is probably not completely rigorous.  It also doesn't look like he coauthored a book on computability.